# at least one match in list quering

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a list of items to search:
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
and documents in mongo:
  doc1 = { a: [1,2] } 
  doc2 = { a:[3] }  
  doc3 = { a:[9,10] }
  doc4 = { a:[1,10] }

I need to query all documents where at least one parameter match

doc1,doc2,doc4 is ok and doc3 is not

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MongoDB shell you can retrieve the documents that match with

```
db.doc.find({"a":{"$in":[1,2,3,4,5,6]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda300b92a26e01f4bc2f"), "a" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda330b92a26e01f4bc30"), "a" : [ 3 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda3c0b92a26e01f4bc32"), "a" : [ 1, 10 ] }
```

when your collection seems like:

```
db.doc.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda300b92a26e01f4bc2f"), "a" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda330b92a26e01f4bc30"), "a" : [ 3 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda370b92a26e01f4bc31"), "a" : [ 9, 10 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e8eda3c0b92a26e01f4bc32"), "a" : [ 1, 10 ] }
```